# Internal Server Error - IAuthentication

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

Estou com o problema apresentado abaixo e não sei como resolver, o sistema está reclamando que não consegue acessar minha classe IAuthentication.

segue abaixo o erro apresentado.

[image: Tela do erro na compilação da view Register]

Abaixo código da minha controller

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using MeuConsultorio.Domain.Account;
using MeuConsultorio.Web.ViewsModels.Account;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace MeuConsultorio.Web.Controllers
{
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IAuthentication _authentication;
        private readonly IManager _manager;
        private readonly ILogger _logger;


        public AccountController(IAuthentication authentication,
            IManager manager,
            ILogger<AccountController> logger
            )
        {

            _authentication = authentication;
            _manager = manager;
            _logger = logger;

        }
        // GET: Account
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var users = _manager.ListAll();
            var userViewModel = users.Select(u => new UserViewModel { Id = u.Id, Email = u.Email });

            return View();
        }

        // GET: Account/Details/5
        public ActionResult Details(int id)
        {
            return View();
        }

        // GET: Account/Create
        public IActionResult Register()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Account/Create
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel viewModel)
        {

            await _manager.CreateAsync(viewModel.Email, viewModel.Password, viewModel.Role);

            return Ok();

            //try
            //{
            //    // TODO: Add insert logic here
            //    await _manager.CreateAsync(viewModel.Email, viewModel.Password, viewModel.Role);

            //    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            //}
            //catch
            //{
            //    return View();
            //}
        }

        public IActionResult Login()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel login)
        {
            var result = await _authentication.Authenticate(login.UserName, login.Password);

            if (result)
                return Redirect("index");
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Login inválido");
                return View(login);
            }
        }

        // GET: Account/Edit/5
        public ActionResult Edit(int id)
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Account/Edit/5
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit(int id, IFormCollection collection)
        {
            try
            {
                // TODO: Add update logic here

                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }

        // GET: Account/Delete/5
        public ActionResult Delete(int id)
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Account/Delete/5
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Delete(int id, IFormCollection collection)
        {
            try
            {
                // TODO: Add delete logic here

                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

E abaixo código da minha IAuthentication

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MeuConsultorio.Domain.Account
{
    public interface IAuthentication
    {
        Task<bool> Authenticate(string email, string password);
        Task Logout();
    }
}
```

Classe Authentication onde minha interface é consumida.

```
using MeuConsultorio.Domain.Account;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MeuConsultorio.Data.Identity
{
    public class Authentication : IAuthentication
    {
        private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;

        public Authentication(SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager)
        {
            _signInManager = signInManager;
        }

        public async Task<bool> Authenticate(string email, string password)
        {
            var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(email, password, false, lockoutOnFailure: false);

            return result.Succeeded;
        }

        public async Task Logout()
        {
            await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Acabei conseguindo resolver meu problemas depois de muito esforço.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acabei conseguindo resolver meu problemas depois de muito esforço. O problema estava que eu precisei referenciar a minha injeção de dependência na classe Startup.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.

                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });

            Bootstrap.Configure(services, Configuration.GetConnectionString("ScheduleDB"));


            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
        }
```